# Wieso sagt man "des Pharao", also ohne "s"

Tags: grammatical-case

Warum bekommt das Wort "Pharao" manchmal im Genitiv kein -s?

> Die Macht des Pharao.
>
> Der Fluch des Pharao.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eigentlich ist das falsch. Der Genitiv des Pharaos hat eigentlich ein s am Ende (siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pharao))

Aber so, wie vor rund 100 Jahren das Dativ-e aus der deutschen Sprache verschwunden ist (früher: *»Am Brunnen vor dem **Tore**, da steht ein Lindenbaum«* heute: *»Der Ball fliegt an dem **Tor** vorbei«*), verschwindet gerade langsam das Genitiv-s bei Wörtern, die mit einem Vokal enden. Vor allem Wörter, die auf -o enden, schien davon besonders stark betroffen zu sein:

> Der Kurs des Euro(s) steigt.
>   Der Herzschlag des Embryo(s) war kaum zu hören.
>   Die Bahn eines Tornado(s) ist nicht genau vorhersehbar.

Comment: *Der Euro* ist ein **Eigenname**. Dort darf/soll man das Genitiv-s schon immer weglassen.

Comment: @tofro: Wiktionary sieht das anders. Es sieht für den Genitiv singular beide Möglichkeiten vor: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Euro

Comment: Sagichdoch. Beim Euro ist das Weglassen des Genitiv-s *nicht falsch*. Bei deinen anderen Beispielen schon. Deine Antwort impliziert, es wäre falsch.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast Eigentlich scheint dieser Wandel vor langer Zeit begonnen zu haben.  Ich bin gerade auf den folgenden Satz aus dem Jahr  **1968** gestoßen : *..., daß es(...) ein Grab des Pharao Tut-ench-Amun geben müsse.*

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch: Stimmt. Ich beobachte das ebenfalls seit meiner Kindheit. Ich glaube fast, dieser Wandel stagniert. Es gibt derzeit so einen Zwischenzustand: Umgangssprachlich wird das s im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum wenig verwendet, aber offenbar weiß jeder, dass man es eigentlich verwenden müsste, weswegen es in der Schriftform meist (aber nicht immer) verwendet wird.

Answer (score 4):

An sich gibt es zwei legitime Gründe, nach denen man das Genitiv-s weglassen darf:

1. Bei Eigennamen "Das Pferd des Otto"
2. Bei (noch) nicht eingedeutschten Wörtern aus einer fremden Sprache "Die Kurven des pacific highway"

Keiner der beiden Fälle scheint bei deinem Beispiel zuzutreffen (man könnte möglicherweise einen Eigennamen daherreden, das halte ich aber für unrichtig), das Weglassen des Genitiv-s ist also eher einer Veränderung der Sprache, die zunehmend das -s auch bei "normalen" Wörtern wegläßt, zuzuschreiben, wie schon von Hubert beschrieben.

Comment: Ich denke, beim Weglassen des s des Pharaos interpretiert das Sprachzentrum (üblicherweise im Hirn des normalverbrauchenden Otto) den Pharao als Eigennamen. So würde ich mir jedenfalls erklären, dass "der Fluch des Pharao" akzeptabler klingt als "der Fluch des Tornado" - hier würde ich noch immer ein s anhängen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das ist das, was ich meinte, als ich schrieb "man könnte sich einen Eigennamen herbeireden". ;)

Comment: Ja, aber du sagst ja auch, dass du es für unrichtig hältst, während ich es für richtig halte (also nicht, das zu tun, aber zu meinen, dass das Hirn des s-Weglassers es tut).